# Does large tempdb file size have impact on sql server startup time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, tempdb

Sql server tempdb data and log initial file size is configurable.

Assuming I set it to large values (say 10GB) then will sql server take more time to start compared to if the data/log initial file size were small (100MB)?

I'm asking because during sql installation it says the larger the tempdb data file initial size the longer it takes for installation. Does this also apply to sql service startup?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the *Instant File Initialization*.
Tempdb is recreated all at once at each sql server restart.

To ensure fast tempdb (and other database too) creation, enable *Instant File Initialization* granting **perform volume maintenance tasks** to the sql server service account.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization?view=sql-server-ver16

However, for large log files, you have to wait its creation based on your disks performance, as log files are not affected by *Instant File Initialization*

Comment: I expect that this is true unless you have Transparent Data Encrypted databases on your server. TDE automatically encrypts tempdb - and at that point instant file initialization cannot be performed. I've never tested if there's some workaround - but I doubt there is - so test restarts.

Comment: Totally agree. No workaround